# How to call a powershell regex command from a batch script

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file

I have a string in a batch script. I **do not** want to create a Powershell script or additional files.

All I want to know, how can I get a regex replace on a string that I pass to powershell through my batch.

My approach to solve it::

```
 powershell -Command " replace "%insert regex pattern%" , "%string_from_batch_file%"
```

I want this`%string_from_batch_file%` to be replaced by the regex match. Again, I do not deal with files or powershell outside of this command, I just need a regex replace on a string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace where? A replacement operation always consists of three factors: the source string, the matching pattern, and the replacement string.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't mean to italicize the bracket, I am new to SO, hence don't mind the pattern, I am unable to get the ps syntax correct as I have never used Powershell before

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. Please provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't mean to italicize the bracket, I am new to SO, hence don't mind the pattern, I am unable to get the ps syntax correct as I have never used Powershell before
===========================
input: abced__xyz.ghi23 output: _xyz.ghi23, regex: _[^_]+$

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't bury relevant information about your question in comments.

Comment: hi, what exactly is missing in my question?, all I want is a string to be replaced given a regex.

Comment: First of all, you have unbalanced doublequotes in your code. You asked what was missing, and @Ansgar has already told you, you need three factors, your example shows only two!

Comment: @phoenyx *what exactly is missing in my question?* For instance the input, output and regex information from your previous comment.

Comment: "I do not want to create a Powershell script" - why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace strings invoking powershell on a command line like this

```
PowerShell -Command "& {'yourstring' -replace 'your', 'my'}"
```

or even shorter <sub>cudo's to mklement</sub>

```
PowerShell -Command "'yourstring' -replace 'your', 'my'"
```

Comment: @mklement0, probably because it is 'supposed' to be [correct syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6#-command).

Comment: @Compo: Indeed, as of this writing, the docs may lead one to believe that this usage is always necessary, but it isn't. A [revision is pending](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/blob/staging/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe.md), which will hopefully appear online soon (offline help would have to be updated with `Update-Help`).

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example from comment:

```
@Echo off
set "input=abced__xyz.ghi23"
set "regex=_[^]+$"
Echo expected output: [xyz.ghi23]
powershell -Command " replace "%insert regex pattern%" , "%string_from_batch_file%"
```

This won't work because you used wrong syntax.
Also the inner double quotes have to be escaped so cmd let's them pass to powershell
(or change to single quotes).

I see (at least) two proper Regular Expression to solve this

1. use an RE to match the part to remove `'^.*?_+'` and replace with nothing `''`
   (can be omitted as it is implied)
2. use a capture group to match the part to stay and replace input with it.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\30\SO_51593067.cmd
@Echo off
set "input=abced__xyz.ghi23"
Echo expected output: [xyz.ghi23]
Echo 1st
powershell -NoP -C "'%input%' -replace '^.*?_+'"
Echo 2nd
powershell -NoP -C "'%input%' -replace '^.*?_+(.*)$','$1'"
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\30\SO_51593067.cmd
expected output: [xyz.ghi23]
1st
xyz.ghi23
2nd
xyz.ghi23
```

If you further want to process the powershell output in the batch file,
you have to parse the powershell command with a `for /f` and store in a batch variable:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\30\SO_51593067.cmd
@Echo off
set "input=abced__xyz.ghi23"
Echo expected output: [xyz.ghi23]

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "'%input%' -replace '^.*?_+'"
`) Do Set "first=%%A"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "'%input%' -replace '^.*?_+(.*)$','$1'"
`) Do Set "second=%%A"

Echo first =%first%
Echo second=%second%
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\30\SO_51593067.cmd
expected output: [xyz.ghi23]
first =xyz.ghi23
second=xyz.ghi23
```